# Call react function from JQ function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to call React function (this.clearMath()) from JQ function

```
$('.input-content').focus(
    function(){
        this.clearMath()
    })
```

I got Uncaught TypeError: this.clearMath is not a function. I think it´s caused by JQ that thinks `this.` is reference to selected element `$('.input-content')`.

Am I right? And how to distinguish between react `this` an jquery `this` to be able call my function? Thanks

Comment: `this` makes reference to the scope where you currently are. In this case, you are right, the scope is of the selector. I'm not sure why are you trying to call a React function from jQuery. That doesn't seems right. As far as I'm concerned, it is not possible to call a React function defined inside a React component from jQuery.

Comment: Can you post your code in a jsfiddle for better understanding what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this by doing this:

```
var _ = this;
$('.input-content').focus(
function(){
    //this is still the input
    _.clearMath()
})
```

So you save the this context before the selector so you can access the _ inside the function, its called a [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp).

Comment: @Rúben Azevedo Please let me know where to put this code. in constructor of the component ?

Comment: Its anywhere you need to use the code actually :)
Because inside the `focus` in this example the context changes.
You can even on the constructor save the `this`, but it depends.